# Binding a more than one dropdowndownlist changing only the query

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

Here I am binding a ddl to populate with values like this: Australis(+61). In another place I want to bind another ddl to populate with values like this: Australia. Can I use the same code and change the query? Actually I am calling this function (which is defined in a separate class) at the required locations (different aspx pages). So can I avoid code redundancy or I'll have to repeat the code

```
public DataSet BindDropDownList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT CountryName + '(+' + CountryCode + ')' As CountryName,CountryCode from ACountry";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds, "AUser");
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

This is how I am calling it in one of the aspx pages:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UserFunctions objBindDDL = new UserFunctions();
        ddlCountryCode.DataSource = objBindDDL.BindDropDownList().Tables["AUser"];
        ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlCountryCode.DataValueField = "CountryCode";
        //ddlCountryCode.SelectedText = ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)");
        ddlCountryCode.DataBind();
}
```

@Praveen: this is where I want only the country name

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            UserFunctions objBindDDL = new UserFunctions();
            ddlCountry.DataSource = objBindDDL.BindDropDownList().Tables["AUser"];
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            //ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryName";
            //ddlCountryCode.SelectedText =  ddlCountryCode.Items.FindByText("India(+91)");
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: u want to bind two different `dropdownlist` with the same code?

Comment: I have given examples of the values each of the dropdowns will contain... I was thinking may be I'll only change the query...

Comment: how? I am not being able to do that... As I said I am calling the function at different places...so how do I make it take the required query?

Comment: one more clarification before i answer... u will be getting data from two different tables...right?

Comment: same table.. Its prety simple, at one place I want the countryname plus countrycode... at another I want only the country name...

Comment: @Aditya Nawandar check my answer may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your last comment its pretty simple to do it:

You need to take the value of `CountryName` seperately in your `resultset` as shown below.

```
string strQuery = "SELECT CountryName,  CountryName + '(+' + CountryCode + ')' As CountryNameCode, CountryCode from ACountry";
```

Then whenever you are binding your `dropdownlist`, you just need to change the `DataTextField`

```
 ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryNameCode";   // For Country name and code
 ddlCountryCode.DataTextField = "CountryName";       // for just country name
```

Rest of your `code` will remain same.

Also an important thing to note:
Do not bind your `dropdownlist` directly on `page load`. Use `IsPostBack`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // your binding here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, this doesnt help... And what does !IsPostBack do?

Comment: No error, but it still gives me both - Country Name AND CountryCode..
I dont want the countrycode...

Comment: can you post the updated code in your question....this seems like a case of silly mistake somewhere

Comment: I haven't changed the query in my code. Do I need to change the query??

Comment: yess...see my answer... i have changed the query...that was the first thing in my answer

Comment: If I have to change the query I have to duplicate the complete code... that's what the problem is...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26766/discussion-between-praveen-nambiar-and-aditya-nawandar)

Comment: so when you add the column `CountryName` in your query...how are you repeating the code?? It will your function `BindDropDownList()` do two things - bind drop down with just `CountryName` and bind with just `CountryNameCode`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use parameter, Add New Parameter to this function like this.

```
public DataSet BindDropDownList(Bool IsIndexPage)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();

        string strQuery = "";
if(IsIndexPage)
{
   strQuery = "SELECT CountryName + '(+' + CountryCode + ')' As CountryName,CountryCode from ACountry";
}
else
{
  strQuery = "SELECT CountryName,CountryCode from ACountry";
}
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(ds, "AUser");
        con.Close();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: IsIndexPage?? Can't I provide the page name directly?

Comment: @Aditya Nawandar IsIndexPage is only example name you can use any name.. when you call this function send true if you need india(+91) and send false if not needed.

Comment: So you are saying that IsIndexPage is used as a parameter? So I dont have to use the actual name of the page, rt? I can use any variable name there...??

Comment: Error: A local variable called strQuery cannot be declared in this scope blah blah blah....